# Is Error Boundary safe to use in production?

Tags: reactjs

I implemented an Error Boundary in my app, and when it catches an error, it logs:

```
   TypeError: Cannot read property 'test' of undefined
        at User (User.js:141)
        at Zi (react-dom.production.min.js:153)
        at ka (react-dom.production.min.js:171)
        at Ps (react-dom.production.min.js:259)
        at tc (react-dom.production.min.js:228)
        at Zs (react-dom.production.min.js:227)
        at Fs (react-dom.production.min.js:220)
        at react-dom.production.min.js:120
        at t.unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.production.min.js:18)
        at jo (react-dom.production.min.js:119)
```

I couldn't help but notice the `at t.unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.production.min.js:18)` part..

Should i be worried about it? Why does it say it's `unstable`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is called on `scheduler` in ReactDOM. All methods in scheduler are named `unstable` both in development and production versions.

The prefix probably means that React API is not stable and can change in future versions. It's not unsafe.

Nothing to worry about in relation to Error boundary.